# How can I customize the data to display in Xamarin Forms ListItem's ViewCell?

Tags: c#, data-binding, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to customise a`ListView`'s `ViewCell`. I wish to display a picture, based on the a value in each item source.

If the person is a Male, then show a male picture. Otherwise a female.

eg.

```
public class Person
{
    string Name;
    Gender Gender;
    string SecretNumber;
}
```

So if `Gender == GenderType.Male` then display `male.png`. else `female.png`.

lastly, the `SecretNumber`. I was hoping to replace all of the char's with `*` except the last 3.

How can this type of customisation be done in a `ViewCell` class?

eg.

```
public PersonViewCell : ViewCell
{ ... }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution is to have another property in your `Person` class:

```
private ImageSource image
{
   get
   {
      if (Gender == Gender.Male)
      {
         return ImageSource.FromFile("Male.png")
      }
      else if (Gender == Gender.Female)
      {
         return ImageSource.FromFile("Female.png")
      }
   }
}
```

And then bind to it in your `ViewCell` like:

```
<Image Source="{Binding image}"/>
```

But if you would like to take it further than just an image and restyle the whole `ViewCell` depending on this property I would suggest looking at a `DataTemplateSelector`used [here](http://blog.novotny.org/2014/12/31/datatemplateselector-for-xamarin-forms/)

I must add that it may also be useful to use this static helper class when dealing with cross platform images in code:

```
public static class ImageSourceHelper
{
    public static string CrossPlatformImage(string resource)
    {
        return Device.OnPlatform(string.Concat("resources", resource), resource, string.Concat("resources", resource));
    }
}
```

and you would use it like:

```
     return ImageSource.FromFile(ImageSourceHelper.CrossPlatformImage("Male.png"))
```

Comment: You're answer inspired me to create a specific `ViewCellModel` for this `ViewCell` and then pass that across. This way, I don't pollute my main POCO with silly `ViewCell` dependent logic. Ta!

Answer (score 1):

And another possible solution is to override `OnBindingContextChanged` method:

```
public class PersonViewCell : ViewCell
{
    Image image;

    public PersonViewCell()
    {
        image = new Image();
    }

    protected override void OnBindingContextChanged()
    {
        base.OnBindingContextChanged();

        var person = BindingContext as Person;
        image.Source = person.Gender == GenderType.Male ? "Male.png" : "Feale.png";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using an IValueConverter, well, a class that implements the interface.

Example:

```
public class GenderToImageConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, object parameter, CultureInfo cultureInfo)
   {
        Gender gender = (Gender)value;
        if(gender == Gender.Female)
            return "male.png";
        else
            return "female.png";
   }
}
```